# Jquery UI Tabs with Jquery UI Widgets in tabs acting strange

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, wijmo

I have three tabs in a Jquery UI tabs widget. Inside of the tabs I am creating a Wijmo Grid. One on each tab. The Grid is based on Jquery UI as well. The grid on the first tab seems fine.
The grid on the second and third tabs (the hidden ones) have strange sizing issues. The Grid on one appears roughly 10 pixels wide and the full height. The one on the third tab appears about 50 by 50 pixels.

I know the code on those tabs is fine because if I make one of those the primary tab then it works fine and the other two are broken. So I think it is some sort of interaction between the Jquery UI Tabs widget and the contents of the tabs (a Wijmo Grid). Does anyone know what causes this strange interaction and what I can do to make it work predictably?

Comment: Do you initialize the tabs prior to the grids ? This is maybe happenning because the two other `<div>` for the tabs are hidden... Could you maybe post an url or a jsfiddle for us to see ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Grid does size calculation when initializing. It needs to be displayed somehow when doing so.

You can add `class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"` to make it off screen when rendering.

Make sure you initialize the grids then the widgets. Or you can call `$("#grid").wijgrid("doRefresh");` when the tab is activated that it is contained in.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That got is fixed. I watched your Wijmo presentation from MVC Conf (I think) a few months ago and that was helpful as well. One other question if I may. Inside the wijgrid I put a wijcombobox in the row. The combox is ignoring the height specified in dropdownHeight and creating a huge pull down that goes off the bottom of the screen. Is something similar the cause of this?

Comment: Glad you came to the session! Even better to hear you are using Wijmo! To answer your question, yes, wijcombobox also needs to be displayed when being initialized to calculate height. Try something similar for the combos but use "repaint" instead.